# what is header.seq, header.stamp header.frame_id for mavros topics

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not able to understand the following error (specially first three arguments of the header) with msg type Type: geometry_msgs/PoseStamped. It would be good if I get example for this command

```
rostopic pub -r 1 /mavros/setpoint_position/local  geometry_msgs/PoseStamped geometry_msgs/Pose '[0.0,0.0,3.0]' '[0.0,0.0,0.0]'
    ERROR: Too many arguments:
     * Given: ['geometry_msgs/Pose', [0.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
     * Expected: ['header', 'pose']

Args are: [header.seq header.stamp header.frame_id pose.position.x pose.position.y pose.position.z pose.orientation.x pose.orientation.y pose.orientation.z pose.orientation.w]
```

Here is datatype of msg

```
rosmsg show geometry_msgs/PoseStamped
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Pose pose
  geometry_msgs/Point position
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
  geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
    float64 w
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283904/what-is-header.seq,-header.stamp-header.frame_id-for-mavros-topics/) by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The general command should look like this `pub <topic-name> <topic-type> [data...]`.

So the `geometry_msgs/Pose [...]` part is wrong in your example.
If you hit tab after `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped` it will create you the required data fields and you can fill them out. Not that  the orientation in a pose is actually a quaternion and thus requires for values.

```
rostopic pub -r 1 /mavros/setpoint_position/local  geometry_msgs/PoseStamped "header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
pose:
  position:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  orientation:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 0.0"
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on 2018-02-28**:
what are the variables associated with header seq, secs, nsecs and frame_id?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-28**:
what do you mean with "what are the variables"? The `header` is a standard ROS msg (http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take example on this command:

```
rostopic pub <topic_name> <topic-type> "{header: {stamp: now, frame_id: 'value'}}"
```

Here you can define the parameters for your header (you can also write `{header: auto}` if you don't care about those parameters).

For your application this should be:

```
rostopic pub -r 1 /mavros/setpoint_position/local  geometry_msgs/PoseStamped "{header:{stamp: now, frame_id: 'value'}, pose: {position: {x: 1.0, y: 5.0, z: 2.0}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 5.0, w: 10.0}}}"
```

This is to answer your question but you should really consider writing a simple publisher with parameters/arguments that you could define when executing a rosrun/roslaunch command.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1